# modify phpmyadmin database on server with import?

Tags: phpmyadmin

in my work i have

> **phpmyadmin**

SQL database to work on (locally and on server)

the annoying problem is when i modify the local DB structure (columns,relations,new tables) i'm forced to redo the modifying again on the server DB because when i backup my local DB and import it in the server i get the error (table exists) and the importing operation gets canceled

so how can i import the modified structures in the server without redo them?
thanks a lot

Comment: How are you generating the queries? They should if `exist` checks already. Also the is no `phpmyadmin` database.

Comment: i don't generate any query i use the phpMyadmin UI panel to create/modify tables and i mean mySql database in phpmyadmin

Comment: When you export the (local) BD, you should check -in export method- the `IF NOT EXISTS`

Comment: i'll try IF NOT EXISTS .... a minute ...thanks

Comment: it did work but i have other problem now ... the metadata in .sql file contains Add CONSTRAINT do i need to modify it to alter and add new one by hand or there is an option to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the DDL on another TXT file and when you are finished with the modification process upload the TXT file to the server and execute the DDL.